# Optimistic Locking Unit Test Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest, optimistic-locking

**The Problem...**
Trying to create a test that demonstrates that optimistic locking prevents the save BUT the action of saving actually raises the `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError: Attempted to update a stale object: Invoice` error, blowing up the test. How can I change the last line of the test to correctly express this?

```
  test "optimistic locking prevents save" do
    merchant = create(:merchant)
    invoice = Invoice.new(amount: 9.99,
                          currency: "USD",
                          item_count: 1,
                          invoice_id: build(:invoice).invoice_id,
                          merchant_id: merchant.merchant_id,
                          invoice_type: 'post-flight',
                          invoice_details_attributes: [
                          {
                            description: 'Detail1',
                            item_quantity: 1,
                            item_amount: 9.99,
                            detail_total: 9.99
                          }
                          ],
                          trips_attributes: [
                          {
                            passenger_first_name: 'Josh',
                            passenger_last_name: 'Smith',
                            depart_airport: 'MCI',
                            arrive_airport: 'SAN',
                            departure_date: 10.days.from_now,
                            passenger_count: 10
                          }
                          ])
    invoice.save!
    first  = Invoice.find(invoice.invoice_id)
    second = Invoice.find(invoice.invoice_id)
    first.currency  = "GBP"
    second.currency = "EUR"
    first.save
    second.save

    assert_equal ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError, Exception
  end
```

**I've tried...**

```
rescue Exception => e
 puts $!.to_s
 assert_equal ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError, e
end
```

But I'm getting syntax errors.

`assert_not second.save`
Doesn't get a chance to trigger as the tests errors out before it actually says "yes, it didn't save."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are looking to test whether a method raises an exception, use `assert_raises`.

To use it, pass a block containing the method you expect to raise an error, like so:

```
assert_raises(ExceptionClassYouExpect) { method_that_should_raise! }
```

In your case, I think this would be:

```
assert_raises(ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError) { second.save }
```

I always refer to the Rails Guides on this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#available-assertions.

Comment: I had just figured that out and was about to write out the answer. Thank you for beating me to it!